# Identity of rows in r data frame

Tags: r

I want to compare two rows of a data frame for identity. I thougth the identical() function would be appropriate for this task, however it doesn't work as expected. Here is a minimal example:

```
x=factor(c("x","x"),levels=c("x","y"))
y=factor(c("y","y"),levels=c("x","y"))
df=data.frame(x,y)
df
  x y
1 x y
2 x y

identical(df[1,],df[2,])
[1] FALSE
> df[1,]==df[2,]
     x    y

1 TRUE TRUE
```

Can anyone explain me why identical() returns FALSE?

Thanks,
Thomas

Comment: `identical` checks for "exact equality". That means, also `row names` (which are not the same here).

Comment: `duplicated` is the function you are looking for here to compare rows of a `data.frame` for equality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
identical(df[1,],df[2,])
#[1] FALSE
all.equal(df[1,],df[2,])
#[1] "Attributes: < Component 2: Mean relative difference: 1 >"

all.equal(df[1,],df[2,],check.attributes = FALSE)
#[1] TRUE

anyDuplicated(df[1:2,])>0
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: +1 And also stripping the rownames by coercing to a matrix: `df <- as.matrix(df); identical(df[1,],df[2,])`

Comment: My favourite one is the third! nice!

Answer (score 2):

try this function

```
all.equal(df[1,],df[2,])
[1] "Attributes: < Component 2: Mean relative difference: 1 >"
```

( in general comparing factors may give 'unexpected' results...) In this case `identity`, trying to match everything, finds different `row.names`, you can see that from `dput`:

```
> dput(df[1,])
structure(list(x = structure(1L, .Label = c("x", "y"), class = "factor"), 
    y = structure(2L, .Label = c("x", "y"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("x", 
"y"), row.names = 1L, class = "data.frame")
> dput(df[2,])
structure(list(x = structure(1L, .Label = c("x", "y"), class = "factor"), 
    y = structure(2L, .Label = c("x", "y"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("x", 
"y"), row.names = 2L, class = "data.frame")
```

In this example a simple `==` works:

```
> df[1,]==df[2,]
     x    y
1 TRUE TRUE
```

Comment: @Roland I know, sorry, I mixed two topic/discussion in the same sentence. that was a general suggestion... Rownames are the reason, I posted `dput` to highlight that difference in fact :-)

Comment: @user2481662 thanks, but the best answer is that of @Roland, in particular this:
`all.equal(df[1,],df[2,],check.attributes = FALSE)`